# Get the text of asp.net checkboxlist using jquery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, checkboxlist

Greeting,

if I have asp.net checkboxlist control :

```
<asp:CheckBoxList id="list1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>One</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Two</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Three</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

how to get the text for second item which is (Two) and has index 1 using jquery when it is check or by passing the index of it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560062/how-to-get-the-index-of-selected-asp-net-checkboxlist-items-and-the-text-value-of, asked by the same poster approx 1 hour ago.  Please don't re-post the same questions in rapid succession.

Comment: @mikemanne instead of writing what you wrote answer my other post here to get more points  and to show out your expertize
here is the port:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533824/enabling-disabling-cascadingdropdown-using-jquery

by the way I post this question before I got complete answer there !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox items are given IDs in the following order:

- list1_0 => "One"
- list1_1 => "Two"
- list1_2 => "Three"

Prefix the ID with the IDs of any `<asp:Content ...>` tags that they are sitting in.

You can then reference them from jQuery easily:

```
if($('#list1_1').attr('checked')) {
  // the second item is ticked, do something
}
```

If you are unsure of the ID given to each checkbox, then do a View Source on the page to check.

You could also write a simple function to do this:

```
function isListItemChecked(listIndex, listID) {
  return ( $('#'+listID+'_'+listIndex).attr('checked')==true );
}
```